# sending hex value over udp

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have written a small piece of code in python 3 for sending value of a variable which is in hex over UDP but it is resulting in "MemoryError"

Here is the code

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
message = 0xf1a525da11f6
sent = sock.sendto(bytes(message), server_address)
```

could someone please help me fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

The socket related code is irrelevant, only this is required to replicate the problem:

```
>>> bytes(0xf1a525da11f6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

The reason for the `MemoryError` is that Python being asked to create a `bytes` object of size 0xf1a525da11f6. From the documentation:

> bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized
>   with null bytes

You can use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) module to help here:

```
import struct

>>> struct.pack('!q', 0xf1a525da11f6)
b'\x00\x00\xf1\xa5%\xda\x11\xf6'
```

The format string `'!q'` specifies a signed 8 byte value (`'q'`) in network byte order (`'!'`) . See the [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings) documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I understood the error now. Could you please suggest as to how else could I convert hex number to bytes so that it could be sent over UDP.

Comment: @AmitChouksey: you can `struct.pack()`. See my updated answer.